# Why is spacex trying to land on a barge?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing

Spacex has already landed its falcon rocket on land. Why exactly are they coming for a barge landing. What are its advantages as compared to landing on land.

https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/688842435955261440

Comment: See [Why did SpaceX attempt to land the booster on a barge instead of somewhere on land?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/7753/49)

Comment: The generic answer would be down in the detail which may encourage a strong opinion element to answers here. In this case though there is something from SpaceX on record here http://spacenews.com/spacex-tests-recovered-falcon-9-stage-and-prepares-for-next-launch/ where it says "Koenigsmann said SpaceX is doing the ship landing on this mission because it was not able to secure environmental permissions in time to permit a landing back at Vandenberg".

Comment: ... and goes on to quote “We could land back on land” were it not for the paperwork issue, he said. “We have enough energy on this mission to come back to land. It’s not anything technical.”